# Windows separator issue when upgrade Magento from 2.2.5 to 2.3

Tags: requirejs, magento2.3, xampp

ERROR: Invalid template file: '`C:/xampp/htdocs/Project/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml`' In module: '' block's name: '`require.js`'

Answer (score 0):

Need to modify in core file.

**Path** : `vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\Validator.php`

**Method** : **isPathInDirectories (line no: 138)**

**Change** : `$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path); to $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));`

**Cause** : **Windows separator("\") and magento directories entries("/") are differ.**